# Mysql advanced statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I am having trouble with the following MYSQL query and are hoping that there is someone that can help me with it.

Here is the query:

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM dbcasino_db22.tb_content
> WHERE content_real_folder = 'foldername/' AND content_no < 5099
> ```

This query works but gives me all the records smaller than 5099 that match the content_real_folder - I would actually just want to get the Maximum Result smaller than 5099 and not have the first record matching the content_real folder

My quess is that the end query would look like this - but I am not having JOY with it

> SELECT *
>       FROM dbcasino_db22.tb_content
>       WHERE content_real_folder = 'foldername/' AND content_no < 5099 HAVING MAX(content_no)

If there is anybody who could help, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for that.  The ORDER tells the max result to be on top and LIMIT 1 tells it you only want the first result

```
SELECT * FROM dbcasino_db22.tb_content
WHERE content_real_folder = 'foldername/' AND content_no < 5099
ORDER BY content_no DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks a Million Jason I can kick myself for not thinking about the DESC function :-) :-)

Comment: After you've forgotten it a dozen or so times, you'll start to remember.  That's how I remembered it so quickly this time.

Comment: @Gerald: If the MAX is 5001 and there are more than 1 record with the value, do you still only want to retrieve one? The result will not be deterministic.

Comment: o.k.w thanks for the reply - the content_no is a unique number so it should give me the record that I am looking for - and if it does not exists, then I am hiding the records...

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to sort by content_no Descending and then LIMIT the responses to 1.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right, you want

`SELECT *
FROM dbcasino_db22.tb_content
WHERE content_real_folder = 'foldername/' AND content_no < 5099 order by content_no desc limit 1`